# Call facebook from ViewController not from appdelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

Hello guys i am new about this implementing facebook into my app.I check developer's facebook and the sdk tutorial.But they all show how to open facebook when the application started.I have a button and i want to open the facebook application ask permission and post the users wall from another view controller. Can anybody help me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest two things.

Firstly: Presuming you've read through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/
You'll probably have yourself an appid (an essential component of connecting to facebook).
With this you can have a look at this demo facebook app https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/DemoApp and apply the key to the property 'kAppId'. This will allow you to run the demo and show how the Facebook classes are initialised and make calls, updating the view as you go.

Secondly: Once you have this grounding of a good example, the next part of your question is relatively easy. If you look at the above examples DemoAppViewController you'll notice that you can start the entire Facebook login process by creating a new instance of the FBConnect class (and it's appropriate delegate). This means that you can link it to a button that updates a new view as long as this new view has the delegate contained or some way to update itself to say "Hey, I'm logged in"

There are a wealth of step by step tutorials to help better explain what I'm getting at.
I really like this one: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app as it's extremely in-depth and probably works at the level you are interested in.

edit - Additionally, just to hit on passing data between view controllers, even facebook related material, I'd suggest you look at http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html (Some improvements coming too in iOS5)